# Spring configuration split between xml resource and Java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to mix both xml and Java Configuration.

I have a *spring-security.xml* resource that I import in my application boot.

Say this was a part of the initial xml:

```
<bean id="ldapContextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url"  value="${ldap.url}" />
    <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}" />
    <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
</bean>
<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapContextSource" />
</bean>
```

Can I move just this part to be a Java config ? Or would the references be an issue.

Thank You

Comment: Suppose Java configuration for Spring security is available and this [post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-ldap) may be helpful.Furthermore more information is in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can move it to Java Config
Declare configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource(){
        LdapContextSource lcontext = new LdapContextSource();
        lcontext.setUrl("${ldap.url}");
        lcontext.setBase("${ldap.base}");
        lcontext.setUserDn("${ldap.user}");
        lcontext.setPassword("${ldap.password}");
        return lcontext;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate LdapTemplate(){
        LdapTemplate lTemplate = new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource());
        return lTemplate;
    }    
}
```

In your XML add

```
<context:annotation-config/>  
<bean class="com.mypackage.AppConfig"/>
```